# How to make babel correctly use special Persian Unicode characters?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, farsi, xelatex

I try to create a bilingual document in English with parts in Persian and want to use babel (please do not suggest using polyglossia instead, since I want to use a more complex document class and polyglossia seems to break it).

It works fine with pdflatex if I just use common Persian characters (this snippet compiles fine with pdflatex and displays correctly):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{farsi}
سلام
% خانوادهٔ من
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

When I uncomment the second Persian line I get problems with pdflatex because of the [Arabic Hamza](https://unicode-table.com/en/0654/).

> ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ٔ (U+0654)
> not set up for use with LaTeX.

I also tried compiling with xelatex but have other problems with that. Although it compiles neither of the Persian lines is displayed and I get a bunch of warnings regarding the fonts:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'LAE/lmr/m/n' undefined using 'LAE/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 133.

> Missing character: There is no خ ("62E) in font nazli!

(one warning for each character)

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

The [Nazli](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/nazli) font is the default font for Persian/Arabic and shouldn't have a problem with the characters that I used.

I tried setting up different fonts with the `\babelfont` command when using xelatex but that did not yield different results.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with `pdftex`, but I’m not sure why it happens.  With `xetex`, the setup is quite different:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=bidi, english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=fa]{farsi}
\babelfont[farsi]{rm}{Nazli.ttf}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{farsi}
سلام خانوادهٔ من
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That actually fixes the problem for xetex, thanks (and sorry for the late reply, I dropped this project during the holidays). Unfortunately this still breaks  the document class I want to use, so if anyone has any input for the pdftex part of the problem I would be grateful.